# Optimizing web page for different resolution monitors

Tags: css, resolution, monitor

I have been working on a site, found [here](http://blacktiephotographers.com), and it looks fine on my monitor (1440 x 900) however it looks very plain when displayed on an oversized monitor. I give the outer box an absolute height and width and this is obviously the reasoning for my issue but what could I do to fix this problem when the images are all a fixed height and width?

I read somewhere that I could do a check to see what dimensions the monitor is on page load - would anyone recommend this?

On a larger monitor there is a lot of blank space to the left and right, and also below the outer box.

thank you for any help!

-Evan

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? You can use **CSS 3 Media Queries**. :) Also, you can consider using fluid layout instead of fixed layout!

Comment: IE and chrome are the top 2 browsers that people are using to get to my site - so those two I would say.

Comment: Ah!!! IE!!! Browsers less than IE 9 does not support media queries, okay, lemme answer your question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using two ways:

1. CSS 3 Media Queries
2. Fluid Layout

Since you said you will be supporting IE too, CSS 3 Media queries won't be working below IE 9, so lets use fluid layout. For this, you can do a few stuffs:

#### CSS Changes

```
#full-height-template-container {width: 1225px;}
#navigation-menu-container {width: 149px;}
#static-frontpage-padding {width: 855px;}

Replace it to:
#full-height-template-container {width: 90%;}
#navigation-menu-container {width: 20%;}
#static-frontpage-padding {width: 80%;}
```

A few adjustments might be necessary.

#### CSS 3 Media Queries

Media queries are one of the most exciting aspects about CSS today. They will allow us to change our layouts to suit the exact need of different devices – without changing the content.

#### Example & Demo for CSS 3 Media Queries

**HTML Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Media query Resolution Dependent Layout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/master.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1>
        Site name
    </h1>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>
            Main heading here
        </h2>
        <p>
            <img class="feature-image" src="fern.jpg" alt="fern" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consect etuer adipi scing elit sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tinunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volut. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="extras">
        <h3>
            Related info
        </h3>
        <p>
            Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
/* ----------------------------
simple reset
---------------------------- */

html, body, ul, ol, li, form, fieldset, legend
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p { margin-top: 0; }
fieldset,img { border: 0; }
legend { color: #000; }
li { list-style: none; }
sup { vertical-align: text-top; }
sub { vertical-align: text-bottom; }

table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td
{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: normal;
}

input, textarea, select
{
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

abbr, acronym
{
    border-bottom: .1em dotted;
    cursor: help;
}

body
{
    margin: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    font: 90%/1.3 "DejaVu Sans", "URW Gothic L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Microsoft Sans Serif", sans-serif;
}

#container
{
    float: left;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #bbb;
}

#nav
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background: lime;
}

#content
{
    float: left;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    background: yellow;
}

#extras
{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    background: gray;
}

.feature-image
{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:999px)
{
    #container { width: 800px; }

    #extras
    {
        clear: left;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 0 0 225px;
        width: 550px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px)
{
    #container { width: 400px; }

    #nav
    {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

    #content
    {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #extras
    {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .feature-image { display: none; }
}
```

**Demo**

You can find a working demo at [CSS3 Media query layout example](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css3-media-queries/media-sample/). Enjoy!

Comment: This is looking good so far, I will test on a larger monitor soon.